# Массив с уникальными значениями

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать функцию, что принимает массив и возвращает другой, с уникальными значениями;

которая также проверяет обьекты и массивы и сравнивает их;

например из объекта

```
[1,2,3,3,NaN,null,2,'str',''str',NaN,null, [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[3,1,2],{1:1},{1:1},{1:2}]
```

на выходе получим

```
[1,2,3,NaN,nulln,[1,2,3],[3,1,2],{1:1},{1:2}]
```

```
function singleExemplar(array) {
    var unique = [...new Set(array)];//отсекаем повторяющейся простые значения

    далее, возможно, нужен перебор и детальное сравнивание обьктных типов, с удалением если сравнение оказалось положительное )

    return unique;
}
```

Comment: да, далее нужен перебор и детальное сравнение

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем отдельный массив, в который будем записывать хэши уже сохраненных элементов исходного массива. Новые элементы с таким же хэшем добавлять в результирующий массив не будем.
Хэш получаем с помощью `JSON.stringify`, но т.к. он вернет нам пустую строку для falsy-значений, то предварительно преобразуем значение в строку:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,3,NaN,null,false,false,undefined,2,undefined,'str','str',NaN,null, [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[3,1,2],{1:1},{1:1},{1:2}];

function u(arr) {
  var unique=[],
    hashes={};
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var currentHash = JSON.stringify(!!arr[i] ? arr[i] : ''+arr[i]);
    if(!hashes[currentHash]){
      unique.push(arr[i]);
      hashes[currentHash]=true;
    }
  }
  return unique;
}

console.log(u(arr));
```

Но, как правильно заметили в комментарии, у `JSON.stringify` есть [ограничения](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description):

- порядок свойств в объекте может не сохраняться, т.е. может оказаться, что `JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2}) = '{"b":2,"a":1}'`
- мы "защищаем" хэши в исходном массиве, но во внутренних массивах/объектах JSON.stringify некоторые значения преобразует в null, что может привести к избыточному удалению элементов из исходного массива

Данных ограничений вполне достаточно, чтобы сказать, что **данный метод не подходит для решения поставленной задачи, а потому не рекомендуется для использования.**

Comment: стоит дописать ограничения для применения _JSON.stringify_